# Print values on printed paper

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

I have 1 bill which contain table, but my requirement is I want to Print values of rows and columns, with correct margin and on correct position. I am using jswing and jTable. Can anyone help me??

Comment: Post the code you have written that tries to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would use not a jTable, but something which intended to print: PDF, *.docx, *.rtf. In this way you have full control on page size and orientation and user may simply edit template in his favorite text processor (f.e., if a new blank has the third column 10 mm smaller).

There are many tools for Java to convert in PDF/doc format. I suppose most of them may insert value in specified field on the template.